# "Unhandled JS Exception: TypeError"

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

I just reset the settings of my IPhone simulator (By hitting 'Reset Content and Settings) and now I'm getting an issue I never had before. Here it is:

[image]

I insist on the fact that the project perfectly worked before this reset, but I needed to clear the local sorage of the app. I did see some posts when poeple changed the location of the `index.ios.js` which is not my case.

I don't have any idea where to search ...

This it a simple react-native project using redux... Feel free to ask me precisions !

Comment: Were you storing any data in the app (maybe something like redux-persist)? If so, it might be that your application is trying to access data that is not there yet. Could you somehow post the code you think is relevant?

Comment: I don't really think it is :/ I do not use `redux-persist`. I'm just using basic `redux` and as I said, it worked perfectly before the simulator reset ...
I was hoping someone had this issue before ^^'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed this by launching this command: `./node_modules/react-native/packager/packager.sh start --resetCache`

Found it there https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/5747 (Kureev's answer).

Hope it helps someone someday