# React Native Unhandled JS Exception: TypeError on new iOS project

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, react-native-ios

[image: iOS emulator error]

I started getting this error when running an existing project with`react-native run-ios`. To try to see if there was something wrong with my project I ran `react-native init EmptyProject` to create a blank project that should work perfectly. I still get this error even with that.

I've looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40681839/unhandled-js-exception-typeerror) on stack overflow and ran `./node_modules/react-native/packager/packager.sh start --resetCache` on both my existing project and the empty project to no avail. Any clues as to what might be going on?

Comment: what version of react-native cli are you using? Try upgrading rn client n node, initialize a new prjct n see if it works

Comment: For react-native-cli I'm using version 4.1.2. I've tried upgrading and react native, but it hasn't had any effect. It breaks even with brand new projects.

Comment: you mean your node version is 4.1.2

Comment: Oh wait. npm is version 4.1.2. react-native-cli is version 2.0.1.

Comment: latest stable version of node is 6.10.1 and rn client is 2.0.1 upgrade n see if it works

Comment: If you are running simulator try changing to a new simulator(quit the current one and change the device model of the simulator)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After several hours of trial and error I managed to fix the problem. At this point, I don't know which specific thing fixed it, but here's all the main things I did.

- Updated node to the latest version
- `brew update && brew upgrade`
- `brew install watchman`
- Fixed all issues that came up with `brew doctor`
- `rm -rf ./node_modules ios android`
- `yarn`
- `react-native upgrade`
- Added `babel-preset-react-native-stage-0` as a dev dependency in my `package.json`
- Added "react-native-stage-0" as a preset to my `babel.rc`
- `./node_modules/react-native/packager/packager.sh start --resetCache`

After all of that my projects have been running smoothly again without any problems.

Comment: `./node_modules/react-native/packager/packager.sh start --resetCache` is what worked for me :)

Comment: Also good to note that after you reset your cache you will need to perform a restart on the simulator to rebuild index.ios.js

Comment: I didn't find packager folder inside react-native folder , how can I get that, any solution ?